# Update plist - swift

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, plist

I'm having a .plist in my app which saves important data. It is devided into the following hierarchy:

1. List item
2. Root - dictionary
3. Settings - dictionary

   1. Setting1 - array
   2. Setting2 - array

How do I write data to the 3.1 and 3.2 arrays? I'm just going to add data to the 3. arrays, nothing more. Im using the following code to read the data and it works great:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SettingsList", ofType: "plist") {
    if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        //   println(dict[settings!][setting1, String])

        settingsArray = dict[settings!]![setting1!] as Array

        println(settingsArray)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a mutable dictionary instead of dictionary. Update data of your dictionary and when you finish, you write your mutable dictionary into file using writeToFile method :

```
func writeToFile(_ path: String, atomically atomically: Bool) -> Bool
```

According to your code you should :

1. Change this line :  `if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` to make a Mutable Dictionary :  `let dict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)`
2. Update It
3. Write it to your file : `dict?.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)`

Comment: merely changing NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) to NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) did it for me. Thanks Ali